# How do I fix these Javascript problems about an input

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, passwords

so I have this password page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="password.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="passwordquestion">
        <form>
            <label for="pswd">Enter password: </label>
            [<input type="password" id="pswd" maxlength="18">]
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="LButton" onclick="checkPswd();" />
            
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkPswd() {
            var confirmPassword = "2pN7Ct24MNO56kc06";
            var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
            if (password == confirmPassword) {
                 window.location="index.html";
            }
            else if(password == "Pessword") {
                alert("Are you actually using that?")
            }
            else{
                alert("Failed Access");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

with the css file

```
*{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    background-color: black;
}
.passwordquestion{
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
}

form{
    width: 31%;
    color: #00FF19;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 24%;
    font-size: medium;
}
input{
    color: #00FF19;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Here's the picture of the website in action(yes it looks like that one Disney+ leak

[image: Here's the picture of the website in action(yes it looks like that one Disney+ leak]

There's a few problems that I'm facing is that:

1, Instead of pressing the 'submit' button to submit I want to change it to just pressing enter (if you enter the password and press enter it will delete the whole entered password thing and I think it basically reset the whole web) and have the button removed

2, If you click on the input box the outline of the box appear and I'm still trying to find a way to make the outline of the input box disappear

for whoever did it I appreciate it bro, Thank you in advance

I haven't tried anything for the second problem but the first one I did tried putting a weird type function on the button and it didn't work :skull:

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue of the outline in the box in your password.css file, add `outline: none` in your original input css settings and add another a option where when you focus the input it also removes the outline, for example

```
input:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

To answer your other question on using the enter key to input password, remove your button and in your JavaScript code you can use `addEventListener()` to check when the input is submitted and when the enter key is pressed.

you already have a function called checkPswd() so you can use something such as

```
document.getElementById("passwordForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        checkPswd();
    }) // change your form id in index.html to "passwordForm"
document.getElementById("pswd").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            checkPswd();
        }
    });
```

in the first part of the code we are listening in the id "passwordForm" (change it to this in index.html for your form ) for it to be submitted. once the form is submitted we use `preventDefault()` we prevents the input from using default form submission. then we run your function, it is similar for the second piece of code but it checks your label and waits for the keyup of the enter key then runs the other code

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. but I didn't quite understand the part of 'change your form id in index.html to "passwordForm"' part. do you mind helping me with that?

Comment: underneath `<div class="passwordquestion">` where it says `<form>` just change it to `<form id=passwordForm>`